# Generic parameter inference and ambiguous function call - is there a workaround?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, ambiguous-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ambiguous call between two C# extension generic methods one where T:class and other where T:struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014036/ambiguous-call-between-two-c-sharp-extension-generic-methods-one-where-tclass-a)

I've this two functions :

```
public static Degrees Convert<TInput>(this TInput input)
  where TInput : NumericValue, IDegreesBased, new()
{
  //Some stuff
}

public static SquarredMeters Convert<TInput>(this TInput input)
  where TInput : NumericValue, ISquarredMetersBased, new()
{
  // Some stuff
}
```

When I call `new SquarredKilometers(10).Convert()`, there is an error saying that the call is ambiguous between the two functions above. The `SquarredKilometers` class implements the ISquarredMetersBased interface.

**EDIT** : So it seems to be normal. Any workaround for this precise problem ? (Interface implementation)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but I may have trouble finding it. Basically, you can't overload by constraints.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my post & question

Answer (score 3):

Constraints are not part of the method signature, so the methods have identical parameter types. Eric Lippert always explains C# the best: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your function signatures are identically - this can not work.
Try implementing your Interfaces explicit.

Comment: Can you detial your solution please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have these two methods, because they accept same number of parameters. 
To make your code compile, you have to either change the signature of one of the methods or, you may implement the interface as suggested by Grumbler85.