# Why doesn't generic constraint help compiler decide among polymorphic methods with optional argument?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, generic-constraints

Given 2 static overloaded methods, one generic and one not:

```
public static T? NullIf<T>(this T value, T equalsThis) 
   where T : struct  // value types including enums
{                        
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, equalsThis)
        ? (T?)null
        : value;
}

public static string NullIf(this string value, string equalsThis, bool ignoreCase = false)
{
    return String.Compare(value, equalsThis, ignoreCase) == 0 ? null : value;
}
```

Test Code:

```
string s = "None";
string result = s.NullIf("None");
```

Generates a compile error as it prefers the generic:

> Error CS0453: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in
>   order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'ExtensionMethods.NullIf(T, T)'

It does compile if the optional ignoreCase argument is provided by the caller ***or removed from the method*** or if the constrained generic method is removed.

Why won't the compiler use the where constraint to eliminate the generic from consideration since it recognizes the incompatibility?

Comment: It also works if `bool ignoreCase = false` is added to the generic method.

Comment: This is because of the rules that govern overload resolution, and its not pretty

Comment: [Relevant / possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014036/ambiguous-call-between-two-c-sharp-extension-generic-methods-one-where-tclass-a). Read Jon's answer.

Comment: I was going to paste a huge spec post, but i think the linked question by @JohnWu and erics blog answer this completely

Comment: @MichaelRandall - Skeet and Lippert explain it all quite well but do they provide a solution for this use case? If so, it's difficult to ascertain. I'm hoping my answer fills the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Both Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert go into excellent detail about how the compiler behaves, why it works the way it does, and so on, but I can't really tell if there's a solution for this use case in all of it.

I have very similar extension methods in one of my own class libraries (and yet, I rarely use them).  One thing I did differently was distinguish between **nullable to nullable** (`NullIf`) vs. **non-nullable to nullable** (`ToNullIf`).  Your `NullIf` for value types is what I called `ToNullIf`.

Let's say you want to start with a `NullIf` that works generically for any type that's nullable.  You can't have both in the same class because the constraint is not part of the method signature.  To get around that, you can put them in separate classes.

```cs
public static partial class ExtensionMethodsForValueTypes
{
    // Nullable to nullable
    public static T? NullIf<T>(this T? value, T? other)
        where T : struct
    {
        return value == null || EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T)value, other) ? null : value;
    }
}

public static partial class ExtensionMethodsForReferenceTypes
{
    // Nullable to nullable
    public static T NullIf<T>(this T value, T other)
        where T : class
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, other) ? null : value;
    }
}
```

The compiler will select the correct method for reference types and nullable value types in the manner that Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert describe in their respective blogs.

The distinction I mentioned above includes a `ToNullIf` extension method, which takes (non-nullable) value types.  It can be in the same class as the `NullIf` that takes *nullable* value types.  It can't, however, also be called `NullIf`.  I'll defer to the Masters once again for the reasons for that.

Fortunately, though, indicating a lift to nullable through a different method name actually can be pretty useful in conveying intent more clearly, as well as having affordances conveyed to you in the IDE, such as when IntelliSense doesn't show `NullIf` for plain value types or `ToNullIf` for nullable value types.  Yet, thanks to the partial matching IntelliSense does in VS 2017, typing "NullIf" will show `ToNullIf` if that's what's available.

```cs
partial class ExtensionMethodsForValueTypes
{
    // Non-nullable to nullable
    public static T? ToNullIf<T>(this T value, T other)
        where T : struct
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, other) ? (T?)null : value;
    }
}
```

If you want to add string specialization on top of the `NullIf` that takes reference types, you can, but you can't have a default parameter without at least one non-defaulted parameter to distinguish it from the generic version at the call sites.  In your case, you need to provide two overloads.  An overload without the `ignoreCase` parameter prevents `NullIf<string>` from being selected because the former is a more specific type match.  One *with* the `ignoreCase` parameter gives you the case-insensitivity you desire.

```cs
partial class ExtensionMethodsForReferenceTypes
{
    public static string NullIf(this string value, string other) => NullIf(value, other, false);

    public static string NullIf(this string value, string other, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        return String.Compare(value, equalsThis, ignoreCase) == 0 ? null : value
    }
}
```

If you have no interest in the parity between reference types and nullable value types in the name of the methods for the **nullable to nullable** case, there's no reason you couldn't drop the `ExtensionMethodsForValueTypes.NullIf` extension method above and rename `ToNullIf` to `NullIf`.  Ultimately, it's the separation into different classes that solves the original problem.

**One final note:** None of this takes into account nullable vs. non-nullable *reference types* in C# 8.0, in part because it's new and in part because the distinction simply can't be made or, if it can, it requires a different technique entirely.